# how to copy specific dict item in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the next dict:

```
d = {"1": "vova", "2":"tata","3": "rere"}
```

I need to pass to function only an item

```
"3": "rere"
```

like this:

```
function("3":"rere")
```

How can I withdraw only a specific item from dict and pass it to function. Key "3" I took as an example. I meant this:

```
function(item from d with key "3")
```

Comment: you mean get the value from the key? You cannot have duplicate keys so any key will only have one value

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can't use the key `3` as the name of an argument. Do you mean you want to pass the value? Or a dictionary only containing one key-value pair (and why not just ignore the others)?

Answer (score 2):

```
key = '3'
function({key: d[key]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your fucntion as

```
def f(key, value):
    # whatever
```

i.e. taking `key` and `value` as parameters.  To call, it for `key`, you then simply use

```
f(key, d[key])
```

e.g.

```
f("3", d["3"])
```